# All the terminal programms close after one second

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-12.04

All the terminal programms like Terminal, xterm and Guake-Terminal close after one second. The error happens after i changed the /.bashrc with exec somescript.py. Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

EDIT: I solved the problem with Strg + Alt + F2 and then changing the bashrc again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doing what you told it to, executing the script rather than continuing with the shell. You can solve the problem by undoing the change you made. (From single-user mode if you don't have `ssh` access or some other way in.)

Here's a tip: If you make changes to the login process, login shell, or login scripts, *do not log out* until you have confirmed that you can log back in. If you change anything that could conceivably prevent a system administrator from logging in, make sure you keep a logged in system administrator console until you confirm the changes work and that a system administrator can still log in.

Comment: Hi David, but how to enter the single-user mode?

Comment: It depends what boot manager you're using. Punch "linux single user" into your favorite search engine. If you know it, add the name of your boot manager.

Comment: i solved the problem with Strg + Alt + F2 and then changing the bashrc again.